# How to go from $dx = -t^2dt$ to $\frac{d}{dx} = -t^2\frac{d}{dt}$

Tags: derivatives

Suppose $x = 1/t$. So now $x$ is a function of $t$, i.e., $x(t)$.

So $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt} = -t^{-2} \Rightarrow dx(t) = -t^{-2}dt$$

This problem is from the textbook: `advanced mathematical methods for scientists and engineers`

[image]

How to go from "$dx = -t^2dt$" to "$\frac{d}{dx} = -t^2\frac{d}{dt}$"?

It seems that I just divide the previous term by $1$ and then multiply it by $d$.

However, it seems unrealistic to me; can anyone please explain this carefully to me? More specifically, can I multiply $d$, which is like an operator to me.  thanks!

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{dt}{dx} \frac{d}{dt}$. The $d$'s themselves shouldn't be thought of as multiplying or dividing. You can think of the whole unit $dx$ or $dt$ as being multiplied/divided, with appropriate caveats.

Comment: @Ian $dt/dx \neq -t^2$ which is what is throwing me off to begin with

Comment: @DavidReed Yep, the whole question is wrong.

Comment: These two expressions are not equivalent. The second one doesn't even make sense. If you show us how you came to that conclusion, or where you got this from, only then we can answer

Comment: I’m trying to delete my attempt, I was thinking something incorrectly. Plus, I don’t know how to typeset the $\frac{d}{dx}$ derivative operators.

Comment: @Ian I modify my question, thanks!

Comment: @Dylan I modify my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the inverse-function theorem and the chain rule:

Inverse function theorem says $$\frac{dx}{dt} = -t^{-2} \to \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{\frac{dx}{dt}}= -t^2
$$

The chain rule says : $$\frac{d}{dx} = \frac{dt}{dx}\frac{d}{dt} = -t^2\frac{d}{dt}$$

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong :

$x=x(t)$, differentiable on an interval $I$, and $x'(t)\not=0,$

then the inverse function $t=t(x)$ exists, and is differentiable $x=x(t).$

Let $F(t(x))$ arbitrary, differentiable, then:

$\dfrac{d}{dx} F(t(x)) = \dfrac{d}{dt} F(t)×\dfrac{d}{dx}t(x),$ I.e.,

$[\dfrac{d}{dx}]F(t(x)) = [\dfrac{d}{dx}t(x) \dfrac{d}{dt}]F(t(x))$,

or $\dfrac{d}{dx}  = t'(x)\dfrac{d}{dt}$, as an operator equation.

With:

$t'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x'(t)}= \dfrac{1}{-t^{-2}}$:

$\dfrac{d}{dx} = -t^2 \dfrac{d}{dt}$.